# npm semver: how to get the latest prerelease version (which has a different patch version) by range

Tags: npm

(I'm new to npm) my npm project depends on a npm-lib(out of my control), "snapshot" versions are being published such as:

- 1.0.0-rc
- 1.0.1-rc
- 1.0.2-rc
  ....

I want to use the latest rc build i.e:  `1.0.x-rc`
so that whenever there's a new rc, my project can get the latest.

so far I tried several sem-versions, but no luck:

> semver.satisfies('1.0.2-rc', '>=1.0.0-rc') // false
>
> semver.satisfies('1.0.2-rc', '^1.0.0-rc') // false

is there a way to archive it?  thanks.

---

update on July 7:

after reading the source code, I think it's impossiable to get the latest rc with a different patch version as I mentioned in my example.
https://github.com/npm/node-semver/blob/v5.5.0/semver.js#L1121

```
function testSet(set, version) {
  for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
    if (!set[i].test(version))
      return false;
  }
  if (version.prerelease.length) {
    // Find the set of versions that are allowed to have prereleases
    // For example, ^1.2.3-pr.1 desugars to >=1.2.3-pr.1 <2.0.0
    // That should allow `1.2.3-pr.2` to pass.
    // However, `1.2.4-alpha.notready` should NOT be allowed,
    // even though it's within the range set by the comparators.
    for (var i = 0; i < set.length; i++) {
      debug(set[i].semver);
      if (set[i].semver === ANY)
        continue;
      if (set[i].semver.prerelease.length > 0) {
        var allowed = set[i].semver;
        if (allowed.major === version.major &&
            allowed.minor === version.minor &&
            allowed.patch === version.patch)
          return true;
      }
    }
    // Version has a -pre, but it's not one of the ones we like.
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

actaully this is also mentioned in the doc:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver#prerelease-tags

> Second, a user who has opted into using a prerelease version has clearly indicated the intent to use that specific set of alpha/beta/rc versions. By including a prerelease tag in the range, the user is indicating that they are aware of the risk. However, **it is still not appropriate to assume that they have opted into taking a similar risk on the next set of prerelease versions**.

I also checked yarn: https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/dependency-versions#toc-pre-release-tags

> For example, the range >=3.1.4-beta.2 would match 3.1.4-beta.2 or 3.1.4-beta.12, but would not match 3.1.5-beta.1 even though it is technically “greater than or equal to” (>=) the 3.1.4-beta.2 version.
>
> Pre-releases tend to contain accidental breaking changes and usually you do not want to match pre-releases outside of the version you have specified so this behavior is useful.

Comment: You question is npm specific and doesn't have anything to do with SemVer. There are no ranges in the [SemVer spec](https://semver.org/).